# Bootstrap space between navbar and carousel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, positioning

Using Bootstrap 3, I've followed their examples to put a navbar at the top and then immediately followed it by a carousel. I've removed the margin-bottom:20px from the navbar but there is still a space of exactly 20px between the bottom of the nav and the start of the carousel.

If I put a margin-top:-20px on the carousel container then the space is gone.

Chrome inspector doesn't show any element accounting for the gap.

Why is the space there and what is the right way to remove it please?

Example is shown here: http://temp.hak.webfactional.com/

Thanks

Comment: Just remove your custom stylesheet and you will be fine.

Comment: Sorry if this is inappropriate place to ask, but what do I do ask the question asker when there is more than one correct answer and that the possible duplicate comment is also true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by this rule :

```
body {
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

As your navbar as a `50px` height *(and what have we got here ? 70 - 20 = 50 !)*, change this padding accordingly and it'll be fine.

Comment: +1 I will go with this answer. just change padding-top; and things will be fine

Answer (score 1):

Add this `css` in your code

```
body {
   padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your css name- **suntrek.css**, line no 1

```
body {
min-height: 1024px;
padding-top: 51px;
}
```

Comment: Aaah me being very stupid not remembering I'd put that there from when I was going through some other examples. Thank you!

Comment: glad i helped! please vote! peace